# Swagger, an int property's Example value different for json(0) and xml(1)

Tags: swagger-ui

I am new to swagger and stuck at a point. 
When swagger UI getting loaded its comes with the example values.
Under one of the API its getting property's example value 0 when I select JSON as Parameter content type, and getting 1 for XML Parameter content type.

I already explicitly defined the example into model definition but its not working.

Have defined the Object like:

```
> myClass:
>     description: bla bla
>     type: object
>     title: my_class
>     properties:
>       time_taken_in_min:
>         description: (Optional) Duration in minutes. Default value is 0.
>         type: integer
>         example: 0    
      xml:
>       name: my_class
>       namespace: urn:project
```

Comment: Give an example of what you have done so far.

Comment: Added a sample code

Comment: Which version of Swagger UI are you using (2.x/3.x)? Does this happen in request examples or response example? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Your example works fine in the latest Swagger Editor/UI: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLwGq.png

Comment: Using swagger 2.0. Its happens in request examples.

Comment: I also tried with editor online, there it works fine. But at my host its displayed wrong

Comment: Screenshot please? You are probably using an old version of Swagger UI.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for answers, because I ran into the same problem. As far as I can see the following happens in Xml. Json works fine.

- int fields with a default of 0 are set to 1. Any other default/example value remains.
- decimal fields with a default of 0 (inclusing 0.0...) are set to 1.1. Any other default/example value remains.
- enum fields are always set to the first value in the enum.
- boolean fields are set to true when defaulted to false.
- it happens in both Response as Request Example Value

**Json Example Values**

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "CB92CD81-F51B-41BD-A864-FF3480C4AC93",
    "common": {
      "datefield": "2017-11-01",
      "intfield": 120,
      "boolfield": false,
      "enumfield": 2,
```

(...)

**Xml Example Values**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Input>
  <data>
    <id>CB92CD81-F51B-41BD-A864-FF3480C4AC93</id>
    <common>
      <datefield>2017-11-01</datefield>
      <intfield>120</intfield>
      <boolfield>true</boolfield>
      <enumfield>1</enumfield>
```

(...)

**Some defintions from the json-file**

```
"enumfield": {
    "format": "int32",
    "description": "Choose from 1 = A, 2 = B, 3 = C",
    "default": 2,
    "enum": [1,
    2,
    3],
    "type": "integer",
    "example": 2
},
"boolfield": {
    "description": "Yes/no",
    "default": false,
    "type": "boolean",
    "example": false
},
"decimalfield": {
    "format": "double",
    "description": "Decimal value",
    "default": 0,
    "type": "number",
    "example": 0
},
"intfield": {
    "format": "int32",
    "description": "Integer value",
    "default": 120,
    "type": "integer",
    "example": 120
}
```

Not all code is shown and some code is changed from it's original because all original names and descriptions are in Dutch.

Comment: Furthermore, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 1.1.0 is used. When the same Json-file is imported into a Azure WebAPI, there seems to be no problem when the developer portal is used.